# Compute $\int_{\mathbb R} (x^2+a^2)^{-s} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals

I want to solve the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb R} (x^2+a^2)^{-s} dx$$
for $a>0$ whenever it is defined. I guess this sould be the case for $\Re(s)>1/2$. A simple substitution gives me
$$\int_{\mathbb R} (x^2+a^2)^{-s} dx = a^{1-2s} \int_{\mathbb R} (x^2+1)^{-s} dx.$$
Using WolframAlpha I tried a lot of particular values for $s$ and came up with the following formular
$$\int_{\mathbb R} (x^2+a^2)^{-s} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \ \Gamma(s-1/2)}{a^{2s-1}\Gamma(s)}.$$
Now I want to know if it is correct and see in this case a proof. As already explained it is enough to prove the formular for $a=1$.

Comment: Do you know the beta function?

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux I have to look it up but that's fine. I've seen it before.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Don't say anymore, I think I get it myself.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Using your hint I solved it know (with use of the Wikiepdia article of the beta function). But now I see that my question kind of was asked before.