# Solving $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{(x^2+a^2)^{1-2s}}{(x^2+1)^{1-s}} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals

I want to solve the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{(x^2+a^2)^{1-2s}}{(x^2+1)^{1-s}} dx$$
for $a>1$ whenever it is defined (I guess this is the case for $\Re(s)>1/2$).

You may use a CAS to provide the answer (I don't have any powerful enough at the moment), but of course I'm also interested in a proof.

Comment: How's your complex analysis knowledge?

Comment: (For what it's worth, Mathematica returns an abomination involving [regularized hypergeometric functions.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1Regularized.html) So there may not be a "nice" answer.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert My complex analysis knowledge is quite okay, I guess.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I guess there might also be a solution involving the Gaussian hypergeom. function (not the regularized one) if you make use of the condition $a>1$. Compare with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237285/solving-int-mathbb-r-fracx2a-sx21-dx (read the comments). It seems like Maple tells us those solution. I'd be very interested in the one with the Gaussian hypergeom. function.

Comment: I tried playing around with contours to see if I could get anywhere with it, but I wasn't able to immediately make progress.  I think I've seen similar integrals done via contour integration before, but they're in notes at my office. If I have time tomorrow (and it hasn't been solved by then) I'll see if I can get anything out of them.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Wow, that would be great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: In terms of the Gauss hypergeometric function, the integral can be expressed as $\operatorname{B}{\left(s-\frac12,\frac12\right)}\,{_2F_1}{\left(2s-1,s-\frac12;s;1-a^{2}\right)}$ for $s>\frac12,a>0$.

Comment: @DavidH Hi David, thx for the result but that looks a little bit strange to me since GHGF is only defined for arguments with absolute value $<1$. However $1-a^2$ has arbitary large absolute value.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain You can uniquely extend the definition to all real arguments less than one by taking [Euler's integral representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/01/01/0001/) as your definition of the Gauss hypergeometric function.

Comment: @DavidH Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know that. But is there another way to write the integral with the GHGF applied within its disk of convergens?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Yes, using Pfaff's transformation: https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/16/01/01/0002/

Comment: @DavidH At https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PfaffTransformation.html it says this transformation holds only for $|x|<1/2$, on your side it's only restricted to $x \notin (1,\infty)$ which looks strange to me. For $x=1$ we devide by zero when we compute $x/(x-1)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the techniques in the notes that I was remembering don't apply to this integrand, so I'm stumped.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert No problem and thanks a lot for looking into it!