# Pfaff Transformation: Where does it hold?

Tags: complex-analysis, hypergeometric-function

Inspired by the comments in [Solving $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{(x^2+a^2)^{1-2s}}{(x^2+1)^{1-s}} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4238397/solving-int-mathbb-r-fracx2a21-2sx211-s-dx) I'm wondering for which $z \in \mathbb C$ the Pfaff Transformation
$$_2F_1(a,c-b;c;z/(z-1)) = (1-z)^a  {}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$$
holds. I've got two contradicting sources: [source 1](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/16/01/01/0002/) and [source 2](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PfaffTransformation.html). By source 1 it would even hold for $z=1$ which I don't understand since the argument $z/(z-1)$ isn't defined there.

Comment: Hello again. Here are some notes on the hypergeometric function that you might find helpful. Theorem $4$ provides a proof of one version of the Pfaff transform. https://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/documents/wi4006/hyper.pdf

Comment: @DavidH Thanks, that's a nice and easy to read introduction to hypergeometric functions.